# Facebook Show Dialog returns null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins, ionic2, showdialog

I'm developing an app using [Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/) and I'm using the [Facebook Plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/) to integrate Facebook with my app.

When I make a post using the show dialog method, it works and the post is shared.
However, if I'm using a device with the Facebook App installed the return of Facebook.showDialog is always null.

```
    let options: any = {
        method: "feed",
        caption: caption,
        description: description,
        hashtag: hashtag,
        href: url
    }

    Facebook.showDialog(options).then(
        (id) => {
            console.log("OK: ", id);
        })
```

I need to get the postId, is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you need it for? (Be aware that you are not allowed to reward users for sharing, or lock content behind it, in any way.)

Comment: I just want to have it for error validating, so that we can notify the user if it succeeds.

Comment: Pretty sure the dialog itself gives the user feedback if anything went wrong.

Comment: @CBroe It seems that OP wants to notify the user in either case, and the dialog does not notify the user on success.

You can always check the user feed on callback (regardless of the value) and get the postId from their first post

Comment: @Manuel, the dialog doesn't give feedback when everything went o.k., true - but I think most users know that already, it's just how it works. And checking the user's feed would require user_posts permission, and I doubt Facebook will grant your app that in review for such a purpose.

Comment: @CBroe Then you would argue that a callback for this method is pointless, right? :)

Comment: @Manuel no I would not. With publish_actions permission one can get the post id back. (But Facebook won't grant it in review for this purpose. But there might be some legitimate uses cases)

Comment: @CBroe Then I agree. Although OP hasn't shared which permissions he has available to determine whether this is a problem with permissions, or a bug in the plugin.

Comment: @CBroe Even ignoring the id, I would like to know if the function was called. It sometimes doesn't even return any Promise.